# Prove $A$ is independent of $B$ iff $A^C$ is independent of $B$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Prove $A$ is independent of $B$ iff $A^C$ is independent of $B$

Moving the **forward** direction:

Suppose $A \perp $B. This means $P(A\cup B)=P(A)P(B)$

$A^C \cup B=B \text{\\} A$

$P(A^C \cup B) = P(B \text{\\} A)$

$= P(B) - P(AB) = P(B)-P(B)(P(A)$ [used assumption]

And, $P(A^C)(P(B))=[1-P(A)][P(B)]=P(B)-P(B)P(A)$

So we have showed it for the forward direction. I am having trouble in the backwards direction.

Moving in the **backwards direction**:

Suppose $A^C \perp B$. This means $P(A^C \cup B)=P(A^C)P(B)$

I need to find a relationship in the second one. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's obvious that only one direction of this theorem needs to be proved, since $A$ is the complement of $A^C$ and v.v. So, I seek to prove $A^C$ is independent of $B$ if $A$ is independent of $B$.

Under the assumption, we know that $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$We also know that $$P(B) = P(A\cap B)+P(A^C\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$$$P(A^C\cap B) = P(B)-P(A)P(B)=P(B)(1-P(A))=P(B)P(A^C)$$This shows that $A^C$ is independent of $B$, so we are done.